# How to add a cardview below of an existing cardview on click of add button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, angular-material, android-cardview

I need to add a cardview on click of this add button and that cardview must be below the previous one and add button should go below the new card view

[image]

Comment: Add button only add one card or it can add infinitely CardViews?

Comment: do you want to add another cardview when add button clicked?

Comment: Yes i want to add another cardview below of it when add button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/baseCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Add" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In Your layout file, You have ScrollView and inside ScrollView LinearLayout. To LinearLayout You add one CardView and Button. Now You have to add onClick listener. So in onCreate You do this:

```
butAdd.setOnClickListener {
    val newCardView = CardView(this) // creating CardView
    newCardView.layoutParams = baseCard.layoutParams //setting params like 1st CardView
    root.addView(newCardView, root.childCount - 1) // adding cardView to LinearLayout at the second to last position
}
```

Result (after adding 2 CardViews, the blue one is the first define in xml):

[image]